# Suppressing "ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used"

Tags: c, gcc, posix, variadic-functions, gcc-warning

Consider the following two macros:

```
#define PNORM( v, s, ... )  { \
  if( VERBOSITY_CHECK( v ) ) { \
    if( ( errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&server.output_mutex) ) ) { \
      PERROR_LOCKFREE( normal, "\tpthread_mutex_lock failed on output_mutex.\r\n" ) ; \
    } \
    fprintf( stdout, s, ## __VA_ARGS__ ) ; \
    fflush( stdout ) ; \
    if( ( errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&server.output_mutex) ) ) { \
      PERROR_LOCKFREE( normal, "\tpthread_mutex_unlock failed on output_mutex.\r\n" ) ; \
    } \
  } \
}

#define PERROR_LOCKFREE( v, s, ... ) { \
  if( VERBOSITY_CHECK( v ) ) { \
    PERRNO ;\
    fprintf( stderr, s, ## __VA_ARGS__ ) ; \
    fflush( stderr ) ; \
  } \
}
```

Now consider an example use of these:

```
PNORM( verbose, "\tSomeText [%d] More [%p]\r\n", 0, ptr ) ;
```

When compiled with the -pedantic option and -std=c99 I get this error many times:

```
mycode.c:410:112: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used
```

The complier is right in complaining about this but is there a simple way I can suppress this warning since I don't care about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combine the `s` argument with the variadic arguments so that you always have at least one argument as part of the ellipsis.  This also allows you to avoid using the `,##` extension of GCC:

```
#define PNORM( v, ... )  { \
  if( VERBOSITY_CHECK( v ) ) { \
    if( ( errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&server.output_mutex) ) ) { \
      PERROR_LOCKFREE( normal, "\tpthread_mutex_lock failed on output_mutex.\r\n" ) ; \
    } \
    fprintf( stdout, __VA_ARGS__ ) ; \
    fflush( stdout ) ; \
    if( ( errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&server.output_mutex) ) ) { \
      PERROR_LOCKFREE( normal, "\tpthread_mutex_unlock failed on output_mutex.\r\n" ) ; \
    } \
  } \
}

#define PERROR_LOCKFREE( v, ... ) { \
  if( VERBOSITY_CHECK( v ) ) { \
    PERRNO ;\
    fprintf( stderr, __VA_ARGS__ ) ; \
    fflush( stderr ) ; \
  } \
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `##` token in combination with `__VA_ARGS__` is a gcc extension that's not part of ISO C99. That's why you're getting the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can [disable](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Warnings.html) warnings just around your macros, or disable the specific warning entirely with `pragma Warnings` in GCC. You could also not use `-pedantic`, since it is, well, pedantic.

Comment: Pedantic is a very good feature to use to help catch minor errors in your code. Warnings are not something to be ignored.

Comment: @David: Sure, but the question was "how do I ignore this warning." `-pedantic` is really only useful for catching gcc dependencies. `-Wall` will catch nearly all the bugs that can be caught by warnings.

Comment: This answer really does not help disable just that warning. Aditionally, at least my version of gcc does NOT support `pragma Warnings`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is simple for you. In P99 there are [P99 conditionals](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__conditionals.html) that would allow you doing something like

```
#define USER_MACRO(...) P99_IF_DEC_LE(P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),2)(USER_MACRO2(__VA_ARGS__))(USER_MACRO3(__VA_ARGS__))
```

So with that there is no need for the `,##` extension of gcc.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Far more elegant.